# Java SE 7 switch statement, when will the default case executed?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm preparing OCA Java SE 7 example. A question about the switch statement:
here is the code:

```
int a = 5;
switch(a){
    default: //print 0
    case 1: //print 1
    case 5: //print 5
    case 8: //print 8
}
```

what's the output of the code?
Here is something I don't understand:
the default will usually be the last condition. What if default is the first condition?
will the default case been matched first?

one step further:
if I change the code, make  i = 10, which certainly won't match the rest 3 condition, but will match the default condition. Given that no break; in my code,
will the program output :  0 1 5 8 ??

**update**
I don't think I state my question clear...
As been suggested, I tried it with code and I do understand the rules about fall through.

And if i = 10, the result will be: 0 1 5 8.

what confused me is that: 
if i = 10

and when we enter the switch statement, which line executed first?

default: //print 0

or

case 1: //print 1

**update update**
thank you guys...
I think I get it...

the default case will only be triggered when there is no matches.

Which means in this case, the execution sequence should be:

```
case 1:
case 5:
case 8:
//and no found yet..trigger the default case
// given that my default case is at the top and no break;
//it fall through and print: 0 1 5 8
```

FYI: I do know how to run the code. And I didn't expect such a huge volume of criticisms saying that "do it yourself", "don't just read and no practice"..

anyway, thanks.

Comment: Isn't it pretty easy to try this out and see for yourself?  Assuming you change `//print ` to `System.out.println( )`;

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#d5e16570 says no break will result in fall through. Check out the rest of the section to see information about `default` in `switch` statements.

Comment: just go on trying it out, it won't break your pc. btw no break statement will anyway execute all cases.

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/443196/java-programmer-SCJP/certification/switch-statement-default-case

Comment: `which line executed first?` the line that got printed first...print using `System.out.println();` if nothing gets printed, then nothing got printed and no line got executed, if one line gets printed then only one line gets executed...so on and so forth.

Comment: @WW. I suppose that when we enter the switch statement, we will match the cases from the top to the bottom. but if we have the default case at the top. will the default case been evaluated first, or at the last?

Comment: `default` will not execute if your `a` is equal to a case you have in your switch statement. Everything will execute if your `a` doesn't match a case in the switch statement starting from default all the way down. Source: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html and http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/compile-136656.html

Comment: @NicolásCarlo I still don't get it. I don't know how to test it.  the question is that the sequence of execution is: case 1, case 5, case 8, default or : default, case 1, case 5, case 8, (and found no match, go back to ) default.

Comment: @StevenZhan if you don't know how to "test" it, why are you doing this certification? Do you know how to compile and run java programs? Do you know how to print out statements? Follow the links above that I pasted to see how to get started.

Comment: Ok, I think I get you... default will only be triggered when no matches in all the case...
in my question, its: case 1, case 5, case 8, and all no match.   and then, trigger default... Since no break;, it will fall through

Answer (score 4):

You should try it and see.  But one thing I'll point out is that there are no `break` statements.  This means it will fall through from where ever it ends up.

So what will happen is it'll evaluate the switch and jump to the appropriate case.  From there it will fall through.

Answer (score 1):

switch is just a specific goto pattern deemed safe for general use.

Gives something like this:

```
if (i == 1) goto lbl1;
if (i == 5) goto lbl2;
if (i == 8) goto lbl3;
lbl4: print 0;
Lbl1: print 1;
Lbl2: print 5;
Lbl3: print 8;
```